# Looking for a coordinator for Book of the Month

Tags: discussion, book-of-the-month

I'd like to propose that we nominate someone to head up the book of the month club; we have [several proposed books to look at already](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1500/choosing-a-book-for-book-of-the-month-club) and probably about as much interest as we're going to get at this point.

Out of the suggestions, I'd like to recommend we start with [Good Questions, Good Answers](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/gqga-5ed.pdf), even though it didn't get the most votes; it is freely available online, it is not directly related to any one Buddhist tradition, and because of the format, it fits well with the Q&A framework. Some of the other suggested books, while interesting, are either directed to a specific school of Buddhism or are not free online.

So, this question is two-fold; please comment on the suggestion to use Good Questions, Good Answers, and please post responses nominating yourself or others to take over the responsibility of coordinating the group.

Coordination probably doesn't involve much; just posting about the latest book on meta and working out a selection for the next month.

Answer (score 6):

I like this selection too. I'm a little shy about coming forward for coordinating, but if no one step up, I guess I could try...

Comment: Hi Thiago. Are you happy to coordinate? I am totally happy to coordinate if you would prefer not to but I think you'd be a great choice. Let me know

Comment: Great! I think that's better, thanks!!

Comment: No problem -I'll post to see if anyone has an objection

Comment: You've received as many votes as the initial question. And your book suggestion in the last post was well received. I think this small group has confidence in ya Thiago.  :-)

Comment: It would be nice to get a non moderator involved, so I'd vote for Thiago on this one.

Comment: Ok. So I imagine we would just get to the reading of  Good Questions, Good Answers? And next month, say around 5th, I could post the question for the next selection, and let it populate until the 15th...

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: Should we put a new question on meta announcing the book group. On of the moderators could pin a featured tag on it. Just a thought

Answer (score 2):

[Good Questions, Good Answers](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/gqga-5ed.pdf) looks like a useful book, written in a very direct manner. I'd be happy to start off with that one.

Just one question. Several of the books suggested, (including this one at 68 pages), are fairly brief. Would there be any interest in selecting two shorter books in months when the main selection is not a longer one?

For instance adding on the 70 page ["Women in Buddhism, Questions & Answers"](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/qanda-women.pdf) might be manageable as they both look like quick reads.

Comment: If I'm absolutely honest I don't have a huge amount of time and also there's other Dharma books I want to read as well as the book club one. I personally could only manage the one book - but I guess people could elect to read one or two. The Women in Buddhism looks like a good one for month 2 - it would be a shame to miss it though

Comment: Ah, ok. Some of the books initially proposed were 400+ pages, so 138 total for the 2 smaller books seemed reasonable. But I understand your position. I'm fine with whatever the group picks. :)

Comment: That's a very fair point. I fact I suggested one that was 400+ pages. I would never finish it in a month - I'm reading it now and really I'll be dipping in and out all year. I was hoping that the month part of book of the month might be interpreted loosely. I guess i might be a slow reader (i think i am to be honest) . :-)

Comment: I think I am too really. Probably very sensible to start out with a smaller book and leave it at that. It's not like anyone who wants to read more on their own wouldn't be able to. ;-)