# The Book of the Month is: "Good Question Good Answer"

Tags: discussion, book-of-the-month

Someone suggested that one good way to use this site can be to study books together, and post any questions from those books that we may have.

Bhante Yuttadhammo [suggested here](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1542/254) that, this month, we could read *Good Question Good Answer*:

> Out of the suggestions, I'd like to recommend we start with [Good Questions, Good Answers](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/gqga-5ed.pdf), even though it didn't get the most votes; it is freely available online, it is not directly related to any one Buddhist tradition, and because of the format, it fits well with the Q&A framework. Some of the other suggested books, while interesting, are either directed to a specific school of Buddhism or are not free online.

Comment: See also [Choosing a book for book of the month club?](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1500/254)

Comment: I really benefited from reading "Good Questions, Good Answers". There was a surprising amount of information in that little book that was new to me. I didn't end up having any questions to post to our site about it; but it was definitely time well spent to add to basic knowledge of Buddhism.