# The Book of the Month [June] is: "Women in Buddhism - Question & Answers"

Tags: discussion, book-of-the-month

The [most voted book](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/choosing-a-book-for-book-of-the-month-june) for this month [June] was [Women in Buddhism - Question & Answers](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/qanda-women.pdf) by Chatsumarn Kabilsingh Ph.D. (Theravada tradition). 70 pages.

> Ven. Chatsumarn Kabilsingh provides answers to questions often asked about women and the ordination issue and related topics. She responds to such questions as: In the Buddha's time what role did women play in Buddhism? Why cannot women become buddhas? What is the Buddhist attitude towards prostitution? What is an attitude of a Buddhist towards abortion? What is the unique characteristic in American Buddhism which might interest a feminist?

---

#### What is "book of the month"?

One good way to use this site can be to study books together, and post any questions from those books that we may have. The idea is that the text should be one that will stimulate our question-asking faculties, which we then apply by asking questions about the content of book of the month on Buddhism.SE. In the beginning of every month, we start a thread here on meta to suggest and vote for a book. By the 15th, the top voted suggestion is selected. Everyone is free to participate.

[Last month](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/the-book-of-the-month-is-good-question-good-answer), the book selected for reading was [Good Question Good Answer](http://www.buddhanet.net/pdf_file/gqga-5ed.pdf).

Enjoy the reading!

Comment: Great, thanks for doing this :)

Answer (score 1):

I read this but I found no questions to ask.

It gave me some previously-unknown-to-me insights into contemporary Buddhist societies (e.g. that there are *mae jis* in Thailand).

Comment: I agree. I was surprised at how much this referenced Thai social norms in regard to Buddhism; but I found it very interesting. I also didn't end up with any questions but did use the information from the book to answer 3 (older) questions.